# Is it possible to skip a line of code when debugging javascript in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox-developer-tools

Say I set a break-point on a line of code in Firefox devtools/Debugger and refresh the webpage to stop at that line. Can I skip the execution of that line and jump directly to the next line?

Comment: @Yogi no, "step over" will execute the current line and stop at the next line. What I want is to skip executing the current line and continue from the next line.

Comment: You are correct.  Surprisingly, there is no way to skip execution using the debugger.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on _why_ you want to skip a line while debugging? Maybe also provide an example to make it clearer for people to understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's currently not possible (as of Firefox 101) to skip lines when debugging.

What you may do is manipulate the code while you're debugging. E.g. you can reset the value of a variable when it gets a new value assigned while the execution is stopped at a breakpoint. Or when the next statement is a function call, you can replace that function by an empty one.
Of course, it is not always possible to turn a statement into a no-op. And doing so may have side effects.

Comment: The problem is the statement I want to skip is "window.location='https://newwebpage.com';". If I cannot skip this line, I have no chance to debug the following code as 'https://newwebpage.com' will replace the current web page. I heard of old Firebug or Chrome seem to have live-editing function that I can edit(remove) the source code on the fly, but I cannot find similar function in Firefox.

Comment: I see. You should mention that in your question. Though generally you should avoid executing code after `window.location` because it's not guaranteed to be executed before the page context changes, i.e. the `window.location` assignment should be the last statement in your code path.
But you're right, the Chrome DevTools allow you to change the code on-the-fly. Firebug didn't have that as far as I remember. (And I am one of the former contributors to it. :) ) The Firefox DevTools are missing this feature so far. See https://bugzil.la/771339.